# "Topic name format is invalid" when trying to subscribe to GCM topic

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, publish-subscribe

I am trying to subscribe my app instance for a topic as described [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_relationship_maps_for_app_instances). Creating a relation mapping for one app instance works ok.

Problem appears when I am trying to create relation mapping for multiple app instances. GCM returns HTTP status 400 with error "Topic name format is invalid" regardless the fact that I match regular expression for topic name described [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).

Even the example POST request from documentation is not working for me again with same error message and I can not find any topic name for which request would pass successfully.

**Request**

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
{
   "to": "movies",
   "registration_tokens": ["nKctODamlM4:CKrh_PC8kIb7O...", "1uoasi24:9jsjwuw...", "798aywu:cba420..."],
}
```

**Response**

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
{
   "error": "Topic name format is invalid"
}
```

Same situation happens for batchRemove request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) insists you use the prefix `/topics/` before your own choice of topic name.

So in your case, your apps need to specify the string `/topics/movies` during the client-side registration process, and the first line of your JSON in the server's POST request you have detailed above needs to be `"to": "/topics/movies",`

Comment: Well, I am quite sure I tried this before without success but now its working :) Thank you. Anyway the example POST request in documentation is wrong so I hope this thread will help somebody in future if Google would not fix it.

Comment: The example looks Ok to me. What did you notice that was wrong?

Comment: Topic name is wrong in the example (first link I referenced in original post). Actually the request in my original post is exact copy of that example.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. Google have got it correct on the second link in your question, which was luckily the page I had read and noted down myself, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to help you!